# parse String date vs Time Zone EEST EET

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Have a problem with parse full date.toString();

```
private final DateFormat dfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
String str = "Wed Oct 30 13:05:26 EET 2013";
dfFull.parse(str);
```

OutPut

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Oct 30 13:05:26 EET 2013"
```

The same problem with EEST

Help please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"` instead of `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"`